# Alignment of Equation

Tags: equations, alignment

[image]

How to left align just circled items to left?

Comment: Hello and welcome to TexSe. You may provide a MWE, so others can see what is wrong with your code or how your code can be modified so so you get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, like this?

[image]
Since you are noveice here, I wrote your MWE (Minimal Working Example) from scratch (what usual I don't doing). Using `siunitx` and `mhchem` packages for writing your equations and `nccmath` for aligning equations near left border of text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\underline{\ce{CO} formed}
\begin{fleqn}[3em]
    \begin{gather}
\SI{1}{\kilo\mole}\  \ce{CH4} = \SI{1}{\kilo\mole}\  \ce{CO}    \notag\\
\SI{16}{\kilo\mole}\ \ce{CH4} = \SI{28}{\kilo\mole}\ \ce{CO}    \notag\\
\SI{15693.94}{\kilogram}\ \ce{CH4} = {}?\ \si{\kilogram} \ce{CO}   \notag\\
%
\ce{CO_{\text{formed}}} = \SI{8860.01}{\kilogram\per\hour}
    \end{gather}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I'm new to both Latex and StackExchange......Again Thank you very much!!